# HIbernate FetchMode Join

Tags: java, hibernate, eager-loading

I have a Parent class with a List of children. I would like to load the Parent by something other than the id e.g. by name...I am using `criteria.setFetchMode("children",FetchMode.JOIN);`
and `criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", name))` to eagerly load all the data for the parent with a unique name. Problem is I get back thousands of results all with the same name...How do I get round this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)`.

This applies a transformation after executing the query which combines the rows for the same root, which is commonly desired on an outer join with Hibernate Criteria.